# MSSQLConnection - raised stored procedure errors not being recorded

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, lazarus

I am using Lazarus together with TMSSQLConnector and TSQLQuery to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database and execute stored procedures. 
I have found that errors raised in a stored procedure (from missing parameters or an exception raised from the invocation of the stored procedure itself) are not made visible to the calling code.

When stepping through mssqlconn.pp, I can see the error being raised during the execution of the following routine:

```
procedure TMSSQLConnection.Execute(const cmd: string);
begin
  DBErrorStr:='';
  DBMsgStr  :='';
  CheckError( dbcmd(FDBProc, PChar(cmd)) );
  CheckError( dbsqlexec(FDBProc) );
  CheckError( dbresults(FDBProc) );
end;
```

And is passed back via the DBMsgHandler function.

However, the DBMsgStr that is built up is never evaluated as the dbsqlexec call does not appear to return a FAIL code.

Because DBMsgStr is not public, I am not able to evaluate it from the outside (nor would I want to as this raises threading concerns).

To reproduce, create a stored procedure that requires a parameter. 
Invoke the stored procedure by setting the SQL property of a TSQLQuery object to 'EXEC "proc name"' and calling ExecSQL (without adding the parameter to the SQL statement).

Answer (score 0):

I asked on core, and it was fixed in (FPC) trunk about a month ago (r28944, oct, 29th):

http://svn.freepascal.org/cgi-bin/viewvc.cgi/trunk/packages/fcl-db/src/sqldb/mssql/mssqlconn.pp?r1=27981&r2=28944&pathrev=28944